# Calificaciones de 0 a 100

Tags: c++

> Hacer un programa en c++ que me pida una calificacion y valide que sea valida entre 0 y 100,
>   una vez que es valida si es mayor o igual a 70 esta aprobado, si es menor a 70 esta reprobado, pero si saca 0, repite curso,
>   si saca 100 obtiene una beca.

este es el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int calif;

    /*
    si es mayor o igual a 70, esta aprobado
    si es menor a 70 esta reprobado
    si saca 0 debe repetir curso
    si saca 100 obtiene una beca
    */

    cout<<"\n\tLISTADO DE CALIFICACIONES";
    cout<<"\n Ingrese la calificacion:  ";
    cin>>calif;

    if(calif==0)
    {
        cout<<"Repite curso";
    }
    else
    if(calif>=70)
    {
        cout<<"Alumno Aprobado, FELICIDADES";   
    }
    else
    if(calif<=69)
    {
        cout<<"Alumno Reprobado, LO SIENTO";
    }
    else
    if(calif>=100)
    {
        cout<<"Alumno con BECA";    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El detalle esta en que el 100 no me lo muestra, sabran en que estoy mal o que falta.

Comment: El problema es como tienes puesto las condiciones. Entra en el caso de que sea `>=70` y por eso en el 100 no sale la beca si no Aprobado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso lo que más se recomienda al verificar una condición con multiples opciones, es siempre evaluar al inicio los casos especificos ( 0 y 100 ) y al final los que abarcarían un rango. ( mayores o iguales a 70 || menores a 70 ).

```
if ( calif == 0 ){
    //Repite Curso
} else if ( calif == 100 ) {
    //Obtiene Beca
} else if ( calif < 70 ) {
    //Reprobado
} else 
    //Aprobado ( ya que no se cumplio ninguna condicion anterior, es muy
    //buena practica de programacion siempre poner los casos especificos al comienzo)
```

Saludos, espero te sirva

Answer (score 5):

#### Vamos a jugar a un juego.

Jugaremos a que yo soy tu programa y tú has introducido `100` dentro de `calif`.

#### Empezamos.

Interpreto `if(calif==0)`, se que `calif` es `100` así que la pregunta es:

> ¿Cien es cero?

Evidentemente no, así que me meto en la rama `else` de la que cuelga otro `if`.

Interpreto `if(calif>=70)`, se que `calif` es `100` así que la pregunta es:

> ¿Cien es mayor o igual a setenta?

Oye, ¡pues si!, entro en la rama del `if` y me encuentro que debo mostrar algo por pantalla, así que te digo:

> ```
> Alumno Aprobado, FELICIDADES
> ```

Dado que he entrado en el `if`, no voy a ejecutar el `else`, así que me voy al final de esta rama de condiciones y me encuentro `return 0`;

Interpreto `return 0`, se acaba el programa.

#### Posible solución:

Puedes comprobar que el número esté exáctamente en un rango en lugar de comprobar sólo uno de los límites:

```
if (calif == 0)
{
    cout<<"Repite curso";
}
else if (calif < 70 && !(calif <= 0))
{
    cout<<"Alumno Reprobado, LO SIENTO";
}
else if (calif < 100 && !(calif <= 70))
{
    cout<<"Alumno Aprobado, FELICIDADES";   
}
else if(calif == 100)
{
    cout<<"Alumno con BECA";
}
```

Comment: aclara en tu juego.. que descarto todo el resto ;)

Comment: señalas donde está el fallo pero no la solución.  aunque siendo puntillosos él pregunta donde falla xDD

Comment: si.. aclara cual seria la correcion tambien ;)

Comment: la primera posible solución es incorrecta... `calif<=69` se come también `calif==0` y la segunda es un poquito confusa...

Answer (score 5):

El error te ocurre porque el caso de `100` nunca es comprobado ya que, al cumplir la segunda condición `>= 70`, ejecuta ese bloque y no comprueba más condiciones al haber sido encadenadas con `if-else`.

Supongo que los mensajes de `Repite curso` y `Alumno con beca` los quieres mostrar además de los mensajes de `Aprobado` o `Reprobado`. Es decir, que además de mostrar el mensaje de aprobado del alumno, si además obtiene beca, mostrar que la ha obtenido. Y si el alumno está reprobado, si además repite curso, que muestre ambas cosas.

El código quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int calif;

    /*
    si es mayor o igual a 70, esta aprobado
    si es menor a 70 esta reprobado
    si saca 0 debe repetir curso
    si saca 100 obtiene una beca
    */

    cout << "\n\tLISTADO DE CALIFICACIONES";
    cout << "\n Ingrese la calificacion:  ";
    cin >> calif;

    if (calif < 0 || calif > 100) {
        cout << "ERROR: Dato introducido fuera de rango (0-100).\n";
        return -1;
    }

    if (calif >= 70)
    {
        cout << "Alumno Aprobado, FELICIDADES.\n";   

        if (calif == 100) {
            cout << "Alumno con BECA.\n";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Alumno Reprobado, LO SIENTO.\n";

        if (calif == 0) {
            cout << "Repite curso.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Actualización**: añadir en el código la comprobación de rango de datos introducidos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es hacer las comprobaciones en riguroso orden ascendente o descendente. ¿Por qué?

Por que en una cadena `if - else`, en el `else` podemos descartar todo lo que ya ha sido evaluado en el `if`.

Ejemplo con orden ascendente

```
if (calif == 0)
{
    // repite curso
}
else if (calif < 70) // si llegamos aqui, calif != 0
{
    // reprobado
}
else if (calif < 100) // si llegamos aqui, calif >= 70
{
    // aprobado  
}
else // si llegamos aqui, calif >= 100
{
    // beca
}
```

Ejemplo con orden descentente

```
if (calif == 100)
{
    // beca
}
else if (calif >= 70) // si llegamos aqui, calif != 100
{
    // aprobado
}
else if (calif > 0) // si llegamos aqui, calif < 70
{
    // reprobado
}
else // si llegamos aqui, calif <= 0
{
    // repite curso
}
```